# Careers Profile fields revert case sensitive changes

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

1. Enter: "Software EngineeR"
2. Tab away
3. Tab back; correct: "Software Engineer"
4. Tab away

Changes are reverted. Workaround is pretty obvious, change the text more drastically, tab away, tab back, correct, tab away, save.

Comment: So, I've been playing around with my profile and I can't get it to do what your suggesting. What browser and OS are you using?